# Determining whether an array is beautiful or not

Tags: python

An array a is called beautiful if for every pair of numbers ai, aj, (i ≠ j), there exists an ak such that ak = ai * aj. Note that k can be equal to i or j too. Find out whether the given array a is beautiful or not!

INPUT:

1. First line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. T test cases follow.
2. First line of each test case contains an integer n denoting number of elements in a.
3. Next line contains n space separated integers denoting the array a.

OUTPUT:

- "yes" or "no"

Why am I getting a runtime error?

```
T = input()

i = 0

while i < T:

  n = input()
  a = raw_input()

  k = a.split(" ")
  for i in range(n):
      k[i] = int(k[i])
  for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i!=j:
            if a[i]*a[j] not in a:
                print "no"
                sys.exit()
print "yes"
i = i + 1
```

I have edited my code but this too is giving me the wrong answer.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: you are not updating `i` in `while loop`

Comment: Please edit your post to include the error you got.

Comment: @bjskistad I am getting the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what error you are getting so I can't comment on that but your logic seems to be off. Try giving `-20,-15,-4,5` as your input. It will say that it is beautiful when it is clearly not. You are only checking if the product of the two biggest elements in the array is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code it can be told that you have misunderstood some part of a question, this is what I came up with after reading your question and there might be a more robust and optimized approach for this problem.

```
import sys
T = input()
i = 0
while i < T:
    n = int(raw_input())
    a = map(int, raw_input().split(' '))        
    mem = {}
    for j in range(n):
        mem[a[j]] = j
    for k in mem.keys():
        for j in range(mem[k]+1 , n):
            if k*a[j] in mem:
                print "yes"
                sys.exit()
    print "no"
    i+=1
```

Comment: I have written a new code for the problem(notice the edit in the question) but still I am encountering the same problem...wrong answer

Comment: Your logic is still wrong, you are check if a[i]*a[i] is not in a, and if the a[0]*a[1] itself doesn't exist in array your program will print no ignoring the products of rest of the elements in a.
And you also mentioned that i!=j in question, then you can't start looping j from 0, it has to be in range(1, n)